# Error with setter method: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a setter for `name` in some class, but I'm having a problem with this.

```cpp
void Cats::setName(char* s) {
    if (this->name != NULL) {
        delete[] name;
        name = new char[strlen(s + 1)];
        strcpy_s(s, strlen(name) + 1, name);
    }
}
```

That's the setter, and I can't write any name for any `Cat` of mine.

```cpp
Cats::Cats() {
    setName("NoName"); <----- problem here and in other constructors also.
    setWeight(0.6);
    setAge(0);
}
```

> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

How can I make this happen? What am I missing? An explanation would be great.

Comment: Note that `strlen(s + 1)` needs to be `strlen(s) + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

`"NoName"` is a `const char*`. The `const` means that no one can modify the characters in it. Your function takes a `char*`, which is a mutable character array. You can't pass constant data to a function whose signature requires mutable data. If you really don't intend to modify the array, then take a `const char*`

```
void Cats::setName(const char* s)
```

or, even better, as Bathesheba pointed out, use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which will manage the memory for you.

```
void Cats::setName(std::string s)
```

Using `new` and `delete` directly, in modern C++, is generally a code smell and should be avoided. We have `std::string` for strings, `std::array` and `std::vector` for arrays, and `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for owned heap memory. Let your types speak for themselves, and the compiler will take care of memory management for you.

Comment: That's great! so I understand I should avoid using `new` and `delete` directly in setters.
I will just use `std::string`, and function would be just `this->name = s`?

Comment: Correct. You should avoid using `new` and `delete` in general. They're low-level advanced techniques that require a lot of care and attention to minimize bugs.

Comment: You have an opportunity to learn about constness. Keep your new and delete, make the function take a const char pointer. The string suggestion is a good one, but it robs you of the opportunity to learn about const correctness

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to figure it out. anyway still no luck. maybe something else is not okay. Will keep trying, thanks :)

Comment: Got it! worked it out with `const char*`.
Thank you so much guys :)

Comment: "*`"NoName"` is a `const char*`*" - technically, it is a `const char [7]` which *decays* into a `const char*` in some contexts, such as in function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this statement in the setter

```
name = new char[strlen(s + 1)];
```

is incorrect. It should look like

```
name = new char[strlen(s ) + 1];
```

Nevertheless the function should be defined at least the following way

```
void Cats::setName( const char *s ) {
    if (this->name != nullptr) delete[] name;

    size_t n = strlen( s ) + 1;
    name = new char[n];
    strcpy_s(s, n, name);
}
```

You are calling the function passing to it a string literal

```
Cats::Cats() {
setName("NoName"); <----- problem here and in other constructors also.
setWeight(0.6);
setAge(0);
}
```

In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays. Thus the parameter of the setter shall be declared like

```
const char *s
```

and the constructor should look at least like

```
Cats::Cats() : name( nullptr ) {
    setName("NoName");
    setWeight(0.6);
    setAge(0);
}
```

provided that in the class definition the data member name is not initialized explicitly with nullptr.

Comment: `if (this->name != nullptr) delete[] name;`: the `if` condition is redundant.

Comment: @prapin It can be also said that a call of delete is redundant in this case.